# SharePoint Client Object Model authentication issue

Tags: client-object-model

I am using SharePoint.Client to connect to a SharePoint website.
The first time it works, but after that I get `401 : Unauthorized error`.

```
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            Web web = context.Web;

            List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
            newItem["MyField2"] = 36;
            newItem.Update();

            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

I have tried entering my credentials also.

```
context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

But the error still remains after a request. I have also encountered that after a time I can make again request, then randomly get Unauthorized.
Is there a timeout on SharePoint server or a restriction on multiple requests?

Comment: There is a timeout for the `ClientContext` object, but you should get an error stating so, not a 401.  You should also be able to make multiple requests.  Do you have permission to the site the context is created for?

Comment: If you make a lot of consecutive request (like couple hundreds) SharePoint can deny the service. It did happen to me a couple of times, but I think error code was 429 "Too many requests".

Comment: I have all the permissions and on the web interface I can do all the operations I want to to from code. Besides that I do manage to get randomly the operation through without an error.  

@dstarkowski Yes, I thought that could be the problem so I created a button that does calls this method, same results, with error code 401 Unauthorized.